# Is it possible to have spontaneous symmetry breaking without scalars?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I have never seen spontaneous symmetry breaking with a fermion filed, or a gauge field. Always scalars. So is it possible to have spontaneous symmetry breaking without scalars, and why?

Answer (score 2):

" By combining the ideas of Nambu in his study of superconductivity and of Johnson, Baker, and Willey in their approach to electrodynamics we construct a gauge theory of spontaneous symmetry breaking which is free of elementary spin-zero fields. The theory contains two fermions and two vector mesons, one of which acquires a mass via the Higgs mechanism. A formula for this vector-meson mass is derived which becomes exact, and nonzero, in the limit as the strength of interaction is appropriately scaled to zero. The vacuum energy is also discussed." John.M.Cornwall and Richard.E Norton's book. look it up.I think I remember the site: http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.8.3338